# Do I need cpanel for my online database for android app?

Tags: java, php, mysql, android-studio, cpanel

I'm making an android app and have an offline phpmyadmin database but the tutorial im using says its cpanel.
I tried setting up an online database but can't figure it out so i looked into a pay per month database. 
So do i need a cpanel database for an app im developing in android studio?

Comment: no such thein as a "cpanel database" (or a "phpmyadmin database") cpanel is just some software shared hosts use a lot to make setting things up easily, its never an requirement

Comment: Thank you, I've clearly very experienced with this. Since I'll be the only one working with it, I won't need cpanel?

Comment: that's correct. cpanel makes some process easier, but does not do anything you can't (assume required permissions)

Comment: Perfect, Thanks a million!

Comment: cpanel i just a UI to control your web server. phpmyadmin is web based UI to control a mysql DB.